# How to get the new value of new replaced string?

Tags: java, string

Im still new at java. Is there a way to get the new string that have been replaced ?

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = new String("wew");
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("w", "61"));
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("e", "31"));
    }
}
```

**output:**

```
61e61
w31w
```

**Desired new output:**

```
613161
```

I want to get the output string `61e61` then replaced the `e` to `31`

Comment: Java String is immutable. `replaceAll()` returns a new String.

Comment: @AxelH not exactly, this question is more about chaining the two replacements, so as to perform both of them.

Comment: I agree @nullpointer but the answer show the correct usage of the feature. Sadly, none mentioned the immutability of `String` ...

Comment: @AxelH While I guess it's nice to know that Strings are immutable, I'd rather say it's not the main part to be learnt here. I did rather focus on the fact that the replaceAll method returns a new String (which is due to the immutability, that's correct) which he has to work with. Nice to know the background though.

Comment: Well @maio290, I feel that without understanding the immutable part of `String`, the result of chaining methods won't be as expected. So, to me, this is the most important part. I tried to quickly explain that in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can chain `replaceAll` as:

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("w", "61").replaceAll("e", "31"));
```

Currently, you're returning two different strings with both your print statements.

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("w", "61")); // returns new string '61e61'
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("e", "31")); // returns new string 'w31w'
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using it wrong. The method [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) of the Class String returns a String.

You have to use the return value again (which can be written in one line):

```
    String str = "wew".replaceAll("w", "61").replaceAll("e", "31");
    System.out.println(str);
```

Outputs: `613161`

Comment: thank you so much sir!. I will try my best learn more on JAVA

Answer (score 4):

Let's review why your code doesn't provide what you expect.

You create an instance with "wew".

```
String str = new String("wew");
```

Then you replace "w" in "wew" with "61" and print the result "61e61"

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("w", "61")); //61e61
```

**Now, the important part here is that the result of `str.replaceAll` is a new instance, so `str` is still "wew".**

```
System.out.println(str); // wew
```

This explain why the second replacement will print "w31w"

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("e", "31")); //w31w
```

---

The reason is that `String` are immutable, so when you try to change the value of an immutable instance, a new instance is return. So to keep it, you need to assign that instance to a variable.

```
str = str.replaceAll("w", "61");
```

Now, the result is kept in the variable "str"

```
System.out.println(str); // 61e61
```

Now, one good thing about immutable classes is that method can usually be chained because the return value is an instance of the class itself. So you can call multiple method at one.

```
str = str.replaceAll("w", "61").replaceAll("e", "31");
System.out.println(str); // 613161
```

But if you want to print the intermediate result, you will need do it in two statement

```
    str = str.replaceAll("w", "61");
    System.out.println(str); // 61e61
    System.out.println(str = str.replaceAll("e", "31")); // 613161
```

Note the last statement, it is possible to merge both assignment and print statement.
First `str = ..` will be evaluated then the result will be printed.

Answer (score 2):

`String.replaceAll()` will return a new String so that your code `System.out.println(str.replaceAll("w", "61"));` and         `System.out.println(str.replaceAll("e", "31"));` need to be chained, else will return wrong result, 

you can use [StringUtils.replaceEach()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceEach-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-) from `commons-lang3`:

```
StringUtils.replaceEach("wew", new String[]{"w", "e"}, new String[]{"61", "31"});
```

Comment: Two reasons why I don't like this answer: 1) This does not tell the OP why his solution didn't work. 2) Importing a library shouldn't be always the solution: That's like "hey, my car doesn't drive any more" - "oh, just use this new car here".

Comment: If your project already used that library and if it offers lot of efficiency and simplicity, I think should just be fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replaceAll("w", "61") //Output = 61e61
str = str.replaceAll("e", "31") //Output = 613161
```

Comment: Your answer contains the solution, but please add a modicum of explanation in addition to your code to show what the problem was and how you solve it.

Comment: thank you so much sir!. i really appreciate it sir